# How can I pass values from Entity to Presentation in c#

Tags: c#, oop

How can I pass the value from Entity Layer to Presentation Layer. I have populated the object Person but when I call it in Presentation it became null.

Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance!

Entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

DataLayer:

```
public List<Person> GetPersonSingleByPersonID(string personID)
{
    List<Person> objPerson = new List<Person>();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    ...

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        objPerson.Add(new Person()
        {
            PersonID = dr["PersonID"].ToString(),
            Firstname = dr["Firstname"].ToString(),
            Lastname = dr["Lastname"].ToString()            
        });
    }
    return objPerson;
}
```

PresentationLayer:

```
Person objPerson = new Person(); //I think error goes here
txtPersonID.Text = objPerson.PersonID;
txtFirstname.Text = objPerson.Firstname;
txtLastname.Text = objPerson.Lastname;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `objPerson` is `null`. Nothing looks out of line but are you sure your text fields properly initialized?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure there are any rows? And that they do contain data? What happens when you debug the code? (you're also not showing the part of the code where the data is actually fetched.. that might be relevant too).

Comment: yes there are result when i do debug in datalayer.. but when i try to display the data from object, it became null

Comment: `GetPersonSingleByPersonID` returns a list. Is it possible that you did something like `var person = (Person)GetPersonSingleByPersonID(id);`

Comment: I think this line Person objPerson = new Person(); is creating another instance of Person that is null.. how can i retrieve the value from DAL to my presentation without instantiating a new Person?

Comment: You can do `Person objPerson = GetPersonSingleByPersonID(id).First()`

Comment: How your Presentation layer is connected with Data layer, i.e. where is a call of `GetPersonSingleByPersonID()` method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass values from Entity Layer to Presentation Layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975964/how-can-i-pass-values-from-entity-layer-to-presentation-layer)

Comment: Don't create duplicates, correct initial question instead:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975964/how-can-i-pass-values-from-entity-layer-to-presentation-layer

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Why `GetPersonSingleByPersonID(string personID)` returns a list? 
   If you want to return a *single* person your method should be defined as `Person GetPersonSingleByPersonID(string personID)`
2. You are not calling `GetPersonSingleByPersonID(string personID)` method at all. Instead you are creating a new 'blank' instance of `Person` class (`Person objPerson = new Person()`)
   You need to call `GetPersonSingleByPersonID(id)` and since you're returning a list instead of a single object (see point 1.) you probably want to add `.FirstOrDefault()`.

`Person objPerson = GetPersonSingleByPersonID(id).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: sorry i have hidden my method inside elipsis, here's my code..
List<oSiteCompany> newSiteCompany = new List<oSiteCompany>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[1];
            sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            sqlParam[0].Value = companyID;

            CommonDAL commonDAL = new CommonDAL();
            dt = commonDAL.SelectQueryProc("pSiteCompany_GetSiteCompanySingleByCompanyID", sqlParam);

Comment: @devkiat - Update your question, the code above is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the GetPersonaSingleByPersonId() method in your data access layer.
create an instance of your DAL and then call the method. this will return the object you want with the details and then you finally assign it to the textboxes.

remember though, the method returns a collection... so you would be overwriting the previous values in your textbox if you are going through the entire collection and writing it to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You had better have a business layer, between data-presentation, in which you get entities from data layer and process them, and convert to presentation layer objects.