# How can I pass values from Entity Layer to Presentation Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I am trying to populate Person object when linkbutton inside gridview is clicked then fetch its associated data and display on the textbox inside a modal. I am able to fetch the data and pass it to Person object, however, when I populate my modal controls, Person object returns null on all properties.

Any idea ton how to pass the value of Person object to textbox controls without without calling Person objPerson = new Person()?

Thank you in advance.

Entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

DataLayer:

```
public DataTable SelectQueryProc(String _storedProc, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter)
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(CommonEntity.ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_storedProc, sqlConnection))
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
                adapter.Fill(t);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        throw new SystemException(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return t;
}

public List<Person>GetPersonSingleByPersonID(string personID)
{
    List<Person> objPerson = new List<Person>();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlParameter[] sqlParam = new SqlParameter[1];
    sqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@PersonID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    sqlParam[0].Value = personID;

    CommonDAL commonDAL = new CommonDAL();
    dt = commonDAL.SelectQueryProc("GetPersonSingleByPersonID", sqlParam);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        objPerson.Add(new Person()
        {
            PersonID = dr["PersonID"].ToString(),
            Firstname = dr["Firstname"].ToString(),
            Lastname = dr["Lastname"].ToString()            
        });
    }
    return objPerson;
}
```

BusinessLogicLayer:

```
public List<Person> GetPersonSingleByPersonID(string personID)
{
    PersonDAL objPersonDAL = new PersonDAL();
    return objPersonDAL.GetPersonSingleByPersonID(companyID);
}
```

PresentationLayer:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {
        case "click":
            {
                // Populate Person Details                        
                PersonBL objPersonBL = new PersonBL();
                objPersonBL.GetPersonSingleByPersonID(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

                Person objPerson = new Person();
                txtPersonID.Text = objPerson.PersonID;
                txtFirstname.Text = objPerson.Firstname;
                txtLastname.Text = objPerson.Lastname;
                break;
            }
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this code and stepped through when a Person is populated in the DAL?

Comment: yes it is populated. i think the new Person() in presentation is causing a null value to the textbox

Comment: Does the Person constructor set the Firstname, PersonID and Lastname to `string.Empty` or are they left to the default `null`?

Comment: public int PersonID { get; set; } i think it is default to null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to get values from empty Person object, not from your DAL. So your method should be like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "click":
                    {
                        // Populate Person Details                        
                        PersonBL objPersonBL = new PersonBL();
                        var objPerson = objPersonBL.GetPersonSingleByPersonID(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

                        //Person objPerson = new Person();
                        if (objPerson.Count != 0)
                        {
                            txtPersonID.Text = objPerson[0].PersonID;
                            txtFirstname.Text = objPerson[0].Firstname;
                            txtLastname.Text = objPerson[0].Lastname;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you are allocating newly created object (yet to be filled) values to textboxes.
Your code should be somehow:

```
PersonBL objPersonBL = new PersonBL();
Person objPerson = objPersonBL.GetPersonSingleByPersonID(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
 if (objPerson.Count != 0)
{
txtPersonID.Text = objPerson.PersonID;
txtFirstname.Text = objPerson.Firstname;
txtLastname.Text = objPerson.Lastname;
}
```